# Putting a bar above an argument so that they touch

Tags: latex, vertical-alignment

I would like to put a line/bar over an argument, so that the bar just touches the top of the highest point of the argument.  I do not want any gap between the bar and argument.  Basically, I would like to create a command \justtouching{A} which resembles \r{A}, but with a line instead of a small circle right above the A.

My initial thought was to try and lower the \overline{argument} command so that it just touches the top of the 'argument', but I couldn't quite figure out how to do this.

I don't necessarily need the command to be operable only in the math environment -- manipulating the \overline command was just an idea that I thought would be the easiest to implement.

Any ideas/input would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!